# F#: Type mismatch error when trying to count number of lowercase letters in a string

Tags: count, f#, type-mismatch

So i'm trying to count the number of lowercase letters in a string. Like this:

```
intput: "hello world"
output: 10
```

This is what I have:

```
let lowers (str : string) : int  = 
  let count  = 0
  for i=0 to (str.Length-1) do
    if (Char.IsLower(str.[i])) then (count = count+1)
    else count
  printf "%i" count
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
 All branches of an 'if' expression must have the same type. This expression was expected to have type 'bool', but here has type 'int'.
```

I've spent hours trying to figure out this problem, but haven't progressed a single bit. How can i print out just the count value that I have? It also says:

```
expecting an int but given a unit
```

Please help

Answer (score 1):

In F#, variables are *immutable* by default. That means that you can't assign new value to them: `count = count+1` does not mean "take the value of `count`, add 1 to it, and assign that new value to `count`" like it does in other languages. Instead, the `=` operator (when it's not part of a `let x = ...` declaration) is the *comparison* operator. So `count = count+1` means "`true` if `count` is equal to `count` plus one, or `false` if the two values are not equal". This is always false, of course.

What you're trying to do, assigning a new value to a variable, uses the `<-` operator, and requires that the variable be declared `mutable` first:

```
let mutable count = 0
count <- count + 1
```

So your code needed to look like this:

```
let lowers (str : string) : int  = 
  let mutable count = 0
  for i=0 to (str.Length-1) do
    if (Char.IsLower(str.[i])) then count <- count+1
  count
```

Another thing to note is that I removed the `else count` line. Both sides of an `if...then...else` expression must have the same type, and the type of a variable assignment is "no type", which F# calls `unit` for reasons I won't get into here as it's best when learning something new to focus on one concept at a time. Also, there are better ways (such as certain built-in functions) to count the number of characters in a string that match a certain condition, but again, one concept at a time.

**Update:** One other change that your code needs that I forgot to mention. You've declared your `lowers` function as returning an int value, but the last line of your original code was `printf "%d" count`, which returns "nothing" (the type known as `unit`). That's where the "expecting an int but given a unit" error was coming from. To return the value of `count`, the last line of your code needed to be just plain `count`: the return value of an F# function is the value of the *last expression in the function*. Here, that's the value of `count`, so the last expression in the function needed to be a line saying just plain `count`, so that that becomes the function's return value.